# URL to access webpage on Xampp?

Tags: ip, port, url, xampp

I installed xampp and made sure config file listens to port 80. I forwarded the http port from the router to the correct computer ip.

Now I am trying to access the index.html like this from another house `http://myip:80` but it is not working. What could it be wrong?
`httpd.config` listens to port 80

Comment: Focus on getting http://canyouseeme.org to find a service on your port from your home.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access "from another house" ?

So you need some way to tell the world that there is a machine on the Internet (on your local network) that will answer that request, and you've started with forwarding the port - good job. Most people forget that.

The DNS needs to be updated with a hostname that resolves to the IP address of the machine  where you've installed XAMPP. A free option is to create an account with Dyndns.com, and choose a domain name of your liking. Then download, install and configure their dynamic update client - this will update DNS whenever the IP address of your "server" changes.

If you want to access your site from within your own network, its easier to add entries to your hosts file (`%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) on Windows, or /etc/hosts on *nix, because you may want to get into virtual hosts later on. :)

Add a line:

```
whateveryouwant A.B.C.D
```

where `A.B.C.D` is the IP of the machine where XAMPP is installed (eg. `192.168.1.2`) and save it.

Then, you can access your website with:

```
http://whateveryouwant
```

If you do decide on a dynamic domain, you can use the same domain name in your hosts file also - like `mysite.dyndns.org`.

Reference: [Do It Yourself Web Server / Hosting - Lessons](http://diyws.ath.cx/lessons/)

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is configured by default to respond only to requests on `localhost`. You will need to edit `httpd.conf` to ensure that the listen directive is not `127.0.0.1` as it is by default.

Comment: Listen 80 is included

Comment: Check for the address to listen on, though. not just the port. I can't remember how httpd configs work off the top of my head, but I think you need to look at the beginning of the virtual host. (sorry, limited internet where I am so I can't look this up easily).

Comment: httpd listens to all ip's. i tried as well port 5900 but it keeps listening to port 80 as i can see from the status window